# An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration.jsp

Tags: jsp, cassandra

Type: Exception report

**Message**: `An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration.jsp`

**Description**: `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request`.

**Exception**:

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration.jsp at line 14*

```
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs;
 int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(fname,lname,email,uname,pass) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
if (i > 0) {
     session.setAttribute("userid", user);
     response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Root cause:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid amount of bind variables
'insert into members(fname,lname,email,uname,pass) values (?,?,?,?,?)'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:116)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Root cause**

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid amount of bind variables
'insert into members(fname,lname,email,uname,pass) values (?,?,?,?,?)'
    org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:188)
    org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraStatement.executeUpdate(CassandraStatement.java:252)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:96)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Root cause**

```
InvalidRequestException(why:Invalid amount of bind variables)
    org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result$execute_cql3_query_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:50297)
    org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result$execute_cql3_query_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:50274)
    org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:50189)
    org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1734)
    org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1719)
    org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:548)
    org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:574)
    org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:171)
    org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraStatement.executeUpdate(CassandraStatement.java:252)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:96)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Your code does not supplier values for query. Maybe you can use a prepared statement in this case ?

Comment: thanks it solve the error, but the data is not inserted in the table created in cqlsh.

Comment: Are you able to insert data from cqlsh??

Comment: manually through terminal i can insert the data in table through cqlsh but not from code.

Answer (score 0):

> Statement st = con.createStatement();

You should use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`. For example:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into members(fname,lname,email,uname,pass) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1,fname);
ps.setString(2,lname);
  ...
```